# how to remove this error "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()."

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jackson

I am trying to make web sersive using this link
http://www.programming-free.com/2014/03/spring-mvc-40-restful-web-service-json.html
I follow all steps as i need static data so I don't want to connect with database .But I am getting error

I follow the step

1. 1 ) New ->dynamic web project

   **2 ) Add all library given in url**
2. commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

   ```
       jackson-annotations-2.0.0.jar
       jackson-core-2.0.0.jar
       jackson-databind-2.0.0.jar
       jstl-1.2.jar
       mysql-connector-java-3.1.12.jar
       spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
       spring-aspects-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
       spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
       spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
       spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
       spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
       spring-framework-bom-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
       spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
       spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
   ```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SpringServiceJsonSample</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**rest-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.programmingfree.springservice.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
  </beans>
```

**controller.js**

```
package com.programmingfree.springservice.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service/user/")
public class SpringServiceController {

    HashMap<String, String> userService=new HashMap<String, String>();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
    public HashMap getUser(@PathVariable int id) {
        userService.put("name", "hello");
        return userService;
    }




}
```

when I hit the server 
**http://localhost:8080/dddddd/service/user/test**
it show The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mpaping expects a PathVariable id, but your mapping pattern does not define it

Either add it to the request mapping or remove it from the arguments, and the mapping will work out. The following is an example with the PathVariable removed

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method =  equestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
public HashMap getUser() {
 }
```

Comment: could you please give more information.give some code

Comment: @user944513 - It is explained clearly here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping - section 17.3.2